# fadeOut CSS não some

Tags: css

Tenho o seguinte código, porém o problema é que ele deveria sumir de vez, mas após um tempo ele volta e fica estático.

Queria que sumisse, que o elemento fosse removido, como posso fazer?

```css
@keyframes fadeOut {
  0% {
    opacity:1;
  }
  100% {
    opacity:0;
  }
}

@-moz-keyframes fadeOut {
  0% {
    opacity:1;
  }
  100% {
    opacity:0;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes fadeOut {
  0% {
    opacity:1;
  }
  100% {
    opacity:0;
  }
}

@-o-keyframes fadeOut {
  0% {
    opacity:1;
  }
  100% {
    opacity:0;
  }
}

.afo {
  width: 270px;
  height: 30px;
  padding: 20px 0;
  color: black;
  background: lightblue;
  font-weight: bold;
  border-radius: 5px;
  animation: fadeOut ease 5s;
  -webkit-animation: fadeOut ease 5s;
  -moz-animation: fadeOut ease 5s;
  -o-animation: fadeOut ease 5s;
  -ms-animation: fadeOut ease 5s;
}
```

```html
<span class="alert_danger afo">
  <label>Usuário ou senha inválidos.</label>
</span>
```

Comment: Você quer dizer  quando a animação acabar, o elemento `span` seja removido do DOM ou apenas que ele fique transparente (invisível)?

Comment: Tem de ser removido

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para definir como inicia ou terminar o efeito de `fade`, pode usar o atributo [animation-fill-mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/animation-fill-mode)

Como deseja que o efeito fique permanente, ou seja, ao terminar mantenha como ficou o último quadro de animação, precisa setar o `animation-fill-mode` como `forwards`:

`animation-fill-mode: forwards` ou no próprio atributo de fade: `animation: fadeOut ease 5s forwards`:

> **forwards** The target will retain the computed values set by the last keyframe encountered during execution.

Ou seja, vai manter os valores do último *keyframe* da animação.

```css
@keyframes fadeOut {
  0% {
    opacity:1;
  }
  100% {
    opacity:0;
  }
}

@-moz-keyframes fadeOut {
  0% {
    opacity:1;
  }
  100% {
    opacity:0;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes fadeOut {
  0% {
    opacity:1;
  }
  100% {
    opacity:0;
  }
}

@-o-keyframes fadeOut {
  0% {
    opacity:1;
  }
  100% {
    opacity:0;
  }
}

.afo {
  width: 270px;
  height: 30px;
  padding: 20px 0;
  color: black;
  background: lightblue;
  font-weight: bold;
  border-radius: 5px;
  animation: fadeOut ease 5s forwards;
  -webkit-animation: fadeOut ease 5s forwards;
  -moz-animation: fadeOut ease 5s forwards;
  -o-animation: fadeOut ease 5s forwards;
  -ms-animation: fadeOut ease 5s forwards;
}
```

```html
<span class="alert_danger afo">
    <label>Usuário ou senha inválidos.</label>
</span>
```

Comment: Ainda não vou dar um +1 porque não sei se resolve a dúvida do AP. Eu tinha entendido que ele queria remover o elemento do DOM, mas ao ponto de não afetar o layout. Ou afetar mesmo, algo como `display: none` ou remover literalmente do DOM usando JS.

Comment: eu entendi, eu respondi baseado no *"mas após um tempo ele volta e fica estático"*, o que me leva a crer que ele queria que ao terminar o fade, ficasse "escondido", mas entendo o que disse, essa perte *"Queria que sumisse, que o elemento fosse removido"* deixa meio em dúvida, mas não faria sentido remover o label para ter de adicionar depois se quiser reexibir a mensagem ;)